# Why does the Xamarin.Forms designer not show windows layouts?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I tried searching for this everywhere, but I cannot find any solution.
I also tried looking at solution properties, project properties, visual studio preferences, Visual Studio extensions, change XAML `xmlns` definitions but I have no clue why this is not possible, and I think it should be standard simple functionality.

When you create a new Xamarin.Forms project that includes 
, you would suspect that there is not only a way to see your XAML design on Android and iOS but also for any Windows platform you are targeting, such as W10 Desktop but also other Windows platforms that UWP supports and that supposedly Xamarin. Forms do support according to the website from Microsoft. You can easily build your project for these platforms, no problem. But I want to see what I am doing before I compile my work.

When opening your XAML design, instead of a simple Android / iOS **and Windows** tab in the design panel, Windows is nowhere to be found.

[image: Where are windows?]

How am I supposed to see how my Windows screen is going to look without an option to see this? In WPF and plain UWP, this works fine, but somehow for Xamarin it only shows Android/IOS, but apparently, Xamarin has full support for Windows (desktop).

I am looking for multi-platform support to create a windows desktop application that is easily portable to iOS and Android. I thought Xamarin could do that, but if I am not able to see what I am doing on Windows in terms of layout, how am I supposed to develop a solid UI for the platform?

I am probably missing some kind of checkbox somewhere (I am hoping), but I cannot find any information about this. Yes, I tried to google. And Stack overflow. And Xamarin documentation from Microsoft. And watch YouTube videos about Xamarin for 20 minutes that supposed to explain the Xamarin multi-platform support. And after 20 minutes I find they only specifically explain iOS/Android but nothing about Windows. So yeah, getting pretty tired of searching and hope someone can be kind enough to help me out.

Comment: There is no designer for XF.  There is a previewer, and it only supports iOS/Android.  I can't definitively tell you "why" that is, but I'd assume that it's simply a question of demand.  iOS/Android are by far the most popular platforms for XF.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I guess I will have to create my Windows app in WPF or UWP and use a good MVVM design so I can later easily port it manually. Just finding it so weird they put it in the market as a multiplatform that also supports windows but you can't see what you are doing. Especially as I don't want the layout on a mobile app to be exactly the same as on a desktop app.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but why is it such an issue to just compile your app periodically and review your layout?  Honestly, seems a little like throwing the baby out with the bath water

Comment: Well it might be possible, but I can imagine when the app grows bigger it can be a really cumbersome task to compile the app, find the correct screen, open another tab etc etc, to find out the button you just placed is a couple of pixels too much to the left. It is so much easier and faster to see it happening "live" in a preview. And why not implement the feature if it is already available for UWP/WPF?

Comment: Currently, Visual Studio does not provide designer for xamrain uwp. please feel free post your requirement on [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).

Comment: Thanks for the link Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of Xamarin.Forms. Although it uses XAML, it has a custom XAML dialect which is not compatible with WPF/UWP, so the built-in UWP designer cannot handle it directly and it will require a custom designer implementation.

But if you want a first-class Windows development experience compatible with Android, iOS and even WebAssembly, try looking into the [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/). This is a UWP bridge with full XAML compatibility with UWP XAML, so your app will look exactly the same on all platforms and provides full templating and styling support. In addition, Uno Platform provides bridge for many non-UI APIs as well, including things like Clipboard, Accelerometer and so on. In the end you will be able to just write a Windows app which will work everywhere with minimal changes.

You can use XAML adaptive triggers to make sure the app works well on each screen size and scales great from desktop to mobile.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that platform looks great, I will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you want desktop version of you app just add UWP or WPF blank project to your solution.

For UWP it goes like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/installation/

For WPF it goes like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf

Right click on your "Project.UWP" or "Project.WPF" project and pick "Set as Startup Project"

and building your solution.